# Take apart a table in row and inherit the style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the structure of my table:

```
<table>
    <col width="40%"/>
    <col width="30%"/>
    <col width="30%"/>
    <tr>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I use **JavaScript** or **jQuery** to take the table apart in rows, and each rows present as tables which inherit it's parent table's style, like the width of columns?

Here is the expected result:

```
<table>
    <col width="40%"/>
    <col width="30%"/>
    <col width="30%"/>
    <tr>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <col width="40%"/>
    <col width="30%"/>
    <col width="30%"/>
    <tr>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Comment: the `col width` property isn't supported anymore (as of HTML5) btw, you should probably replace it with the relevant CSS.

Comment: @Zenith OMG...Is there an alternative solution to convert this table? Actually this is the source file which I should deal with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as mentioned by `Zenith` the `col` tag is no longer supported in HTML5, by if you're going to use it you should also wrap the elements in a `colgroup`.

However, I've made a quick [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2phT/) which should solve your problem, see the JS below:

```
// Create a template by cloning the table and removing all of the rows
var template = $("#original").clone();
template.removeAttr("id").find("tr").remove();
// Loop over the original rows, create a new table based on the template, and append the row into the tbody
$("#original tr").each(function() {
    var individual = template.clone();
    individual.find("tbody").append($(this).html());
    individual.appendTo("#splits");
});
//  Optional, remove the original table
// $("#original").remove()
```

I hope this solves your problem, and my solution should work for any sort of table where you want to extract all of the rows.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2phT/3/) see this. I refereed your answer and code like this. I have so many Divs `class="extra"` which contains a single table.I would like to extract each table's row out and put in a div `class="linediv"`. Thanks!

Comment: `Darklizard` - I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2phT/6/), now you can insert as many different tables as you like, and each row from them will be copied and inserted inside of a `div.linediv`, which in turn is placed into `div#splits` (though you could change). I hope this is what you are looking for. If so, please upvote, and select as right answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I want and explicit enough!

Comment: Sorry for disturbing. If `<div id="splits"></div>` is not pre-defined, and perhaps I have some other divs between `<div class="extra">` , so that I just want to replace the original content of `<div class="extra">` with new created  `<div id="splits"></div>`, what should I do? It seems that I can't call the parentNode of `$("table")` directly...

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. I changed your original fiddle so that it utilised more of the power of jQuery rather than using pure JS. In the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2phT/6/), we iterate over each table, and within the `each` function, the table takes the `this` alias. If you wanted to select the parent of a table you could just do `$(this).parent()` within the outer `each`.

Answer (score 1):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/qq3zb/5/

**html**

```
<table id='original' style="background: red;">
    <col width="40%"/>
    <col width="30%"/>
    <col width="30%"/>
    <tr>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id='newly'>
</div>
```

**js**

```
var settings = $("#original col");
var rows = $("#original tr");
var style = $("#original").attr("style");
for (var x = 0; x < rows.length; x++) {
    var tmpTbl = $("<table border='1'></table>").attr("style", style);
    $(tmpTbl).append($(settings).clone()).append($(rows[x]).clone());
    $("#newly").append(tmpTbl);
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! But if `<table>` tag itself contains style, it won't be copied.

Comment: in your example, there was no style in <table> tag :) anyway, don't use inline style, go for css. Give a class to your table, or to the copyed, and then apply style via css